# iOS mutable array always null

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

heres my conundrum

i am try to put a table view above my view controller

the view loads and is added, the array that i am using for the tableview is always null however so the table is always empty!

here is my view header file with my tableview and mutable array properties

```
@interface IngredientsView : UIView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andIngredients:(NSMutableArray*)ingredientsArray;

- (id)initWithIngredients:(NSMutableArray*)ingredientsArray;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *notesTableView;
@property NSMutableArray* ingredients;
```

my custom init method takes in the array and sets it - here is my custom init

```
- (id)initWithIngredients:(NSMutableArray*)ingredientsArray;
{


self.ingredients = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.ingredients=ingredientsArray;

NSLog(@"hello from init %lu", (unsigned long)[self.ingredients count]);




if (self) {
    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self class]] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];


    UIImageView* view = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ingredients background.png"]];

    self.notesTableView.backgroundView=view;


    self.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:0.6f];

    self.notesTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.notesTableView.delegate = self;



    UIGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(close)];

    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


    [self.notesTableView reloadData];

}
return self;
```

}

inside the init method the self.ingredients array will return a count (e.g. 6 objects) to NSlog

but in my delegate table view method numberOfSectionsFor:index path it always returns 0 as if the array is nil

i have tried

- using a instance array instead
- synthesising the array and setting it from my view controller
- sticking the array on a singleton and grabbing the array from a singleton

all return 0 for number of sections ?

is the tableview nil?

i normally use table view controllers and don't have much experience using just tableviews is there something i have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your setting self.ingredients=ingredientsArray; and then on the following line setting self to a  nib that you your loading, overwriting self. Move the self.ingredients assignment to after you set self to the nib.

Comment: ah of course - thanks - thats why no matter what i did it was wiped

Answer (score 0):

Which of your initializers are called?  If you are being loaded from an xib file, certainly

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andIngredients:
```

is not called

`- (id) initWithFrame:` is the designated initializer for views. so it will be called when loading views from a nib file.

In any case , the first thing your `initWith...` code should do is:

```
self = [super initWithFrame: ... ]
if (self) 
{
   ...
}
```

The MOST critical problem:

You are assigning `self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self class]] owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];`

You just blasted over `self` which is being initialized.

If you were wanting `IngredientsView` to be loaded from the XIB file, you might also consider implementing `-(void) awakeFromNib {...}` to set your properties, or set the properties in the - (self) InitWithFrame: .... `after calling`[super initWIthFrame:rect]`